# Get sql query value in Django

Tags: python, html, sql, django, django-models

how can I get only the value of the following query. I just want to get the value of name, and not a dict, since in laravel you can use the -> get () in django that I can use.

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM person WHERE id=2")
    fila=cursor.fetchall()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use indexing. Indexing will return the value that the particular key was assigned. So you could first

```
print(cursor.fetchall())
```

and then you could identify which index you need to return. Then you can either use a for loop or directly index depending on your necessity

```
fila = cursor.fetchall()[indexvalue]
```